# It's possible to draw MapPolygon with a hole on Map in QML?

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qtpositioning

In C++ I can use QPainterPath::subtracted for drawing polygon with hole, but I don't know, how it's possible in QML Map.

Comment: Which Qt Location plugin are you using?

Comment: OpenStreetMap plugin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since [Qt 5.13](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtlocation.git/tree/dist/changes-5.13.0/?h=v5.13.0) is possible with the [Mapbox GL Plugin](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/location-plugin-mapboxgl.html), for example using a [QGeoPolygon](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgeopolygon.html), you could also use GeoJSON. For example:

**main.cpp**

```cpp
#include <QGeoPolygon>
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QGeoPolygon polygon;
    polygon.setPath({{51.11, 17.13},
                     {50.42, 30.54},
                     {58.36, 26.70},
                     {51.11, 17.13}});
    polygon.addHole({{54.36, 23.46},
                     {51.91, 20.52},
                     {51.50, 28.25},
                     {54.36, 26.80},
                     {54.36, 23.46}});

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("poly", QVariant::fromValue(polygon));
    const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));
    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
                     &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
        if (!obj && url == objUrl)
            QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
    }, Qt::QueuedConnection);
    engine.load(url);

    return app.exec();
}
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtLocation 5.13
import QtPositioning 5.13

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    Map {
        anchors.fill: parent
        center: QtPositioning.coordinate(52, 22)
        plugin: Plugin {
            name: "mapboxgl"
        }
        zoomLevel: 4
        MapPolygon {
            color: "red"
            border.color: "green"
            border.width: 2
            smooth: true
            opacity: 0.25
            geoShape: poly
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: What is geoShape? I can't find documentation about it https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.13/qml-qtlocation-mappolygon.html

Comment: @Pavel As you pointed out recently it has been implemented so it seems that it has not yet been added in the docs

Comment: Just ran this code but I get nothing on the screen, application output shows this message: "The geoservices provider is not supported." What should I add/remove to make this code to work please?

Answer (score 0):

The following QML code should work too, without the requirement for C++. Tested on Qt 6.5.

```
MapPolygon {
        id: mapPoly
        geoShape: QtPositioning.polygon(
            [
                QtPositioning.coordinate(51.11, 17.13),
                QtPositioning.coordinate(50.42, 30.54),
                QtPositioning.coordinate(58.36, 26.70)
            ],
            [
                [
                   QtPositioning.coordinate(54.36, 23.46),
                   QtPositioning.coordinate(51.91, 20.52),
                   QtPositioning.coordinate(51.50, 28.25),
                   QtPositioning.coordinate(54.36, 26.80)
               ]
            ]
        )
```